# nmap finding supported SSL/TLS versions when port is open but filtered

Tags: http, ssl, https, nmap, port-scanning

So I have a range of IPs, which I want to find out the supported TLS version on port 443. 
These IPs all have port 443 open. Most of them reported the supported TLS versions simply by using the nmap --ssl-enum-script script.

Yet now I have a couple of IPs that reported the port as status "filtered".
I found out, that this is caused by a firewall blocking the scan.

So then I tried to scan it with the --script firewall-bypass script:

```
nmap --script firewall-bypass --script-args firewall-bypass.helper="http" <ip> -p 443 --script ssl-enum-ciphers
```

To get the state of the port, this works, but I still don't know which TLS versions are supported:

```
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-06-02 16:07 W. Europe Daylight Time
Nmap scan report for <host> (<ip>)
Host is up (0.032s latency).

PORT    STATE SERVICE
443/tcp open  https

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.16 seconds
```

Having both of the scripts running at once should not be a problem. I have tested this with different ports, and it works on them -> they display the supported TLS versions.

How can I find out the supported TLS versions of these hosts?
Is there an option with nmap, or can i do it with a different programm (like powershell or something)?

Thanks for your help

Comment: According to the documentation the original firewall-bypass script only supports ftp. You are using http - which script do you use. In any way detecting TLS versions require to be able to send TLS client hello packets to the port. I am not sure if the helper system support this. From what I read it only allows to detect open ports.